# Report Error in salesforce

Tags: reports-api

While accessing the report for particular user for particular profile i am getting error, while clicking the report

System administrator profile can able to see the report

I have checked the conditon

1. The object visbility is applicable to that profile
2. The object which is using in report Enable Reports checkbox is checked
3. There is no installed packages belong to that object
4. I have checked system permissions to that particular profile , i have given report  access

Still i am getting report error in salesforce for particular profile. what may be the issue?[image]

Comment: Does the user have permission to access the folder the report is saved in and being run from? That sounds like the one thing you may not have checked.

Comment: Yes the user has folder access

Comment: Since you get "Obsolete Report" as part of the error message, who is the owner of the report? Are they still an active user? It could be that the person who is the runAs user or who owns the report, is no longer part of your org.

Comment: go through this:-  http://www.simplysfdc.com/2014/06/salesforce-obsolete-report.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reports can be "obsolete" for a number of reasons. Since it affects only some users, it may be one of the following.

The object is "In Development" so only administrators can see it. Change the status of the object to "Deployed".

The lookup field is "hidden" to that profile, so they can't report on the relationship. Add "Visible" to the profile's field level security for the field.

The profile does not have Read access to the child or parent object. Add "Read" to the object permissions for both parent and child objects to the profile.

At least one object is in a managed package, and the user does not have a license to use the package. Add a package license to the affected users.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship on the object might have changed from Master Detail to Lookup or lookup to master detail

- Please check if the relationship between the objects has changed.
- If the relation was changed, the old reports are obsolete and new reports need to be created.

The users might not have access to the object that is reported on.

- Please check if the users have access to the respective Object
- Give the Users Access to the Objects